# Can I bind a class member function as static function in lua using luabind?

Tags: c++, lua, luabind

In C++, I have a global variable named as g. I want to bind it as static function so that lua don't need to create a Global variable, and can call its member function as static function.

c++ code:

```
class Global
{
    int test();
};

Global g;
```

lua code:

```
Global.test() // call g.test() in c++
```

I know the bind method, but it bind test as a member function. How can I bind the member function test as static method in lua?

```
    module(L)
    [
        class_<Global>("Global")
        .def("test", &Global::test)
    ];
```

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler to bind `[](){g.test();}`?

Comment: Yes, definitely. But the lua interface has been used by others, I could only re-implement the c++ side.

Comment: @Jayce can you elaborate? The rf's solution shouldn't change the function from the Lua side.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Perhaps I didn't quite got rf's idea. I want to bind a c++ non-member function as static member function in lua as described above. But rf's solution bind g.test to a free function. Could you give me some code about how to use rf's solution? Thanks.

Comment: @Jayce Oh, so from the Lua side this specifically needs to be called as a static function of that exposed class? Eh, that's why I never bother with exposing that 1:1. How about you actually make `test` a static method in C++?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz If it can not bind to a member function, I have to come up with some workaround  to make the method static.

Comment: @Jayce So again, how about making that method static?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Making that method static works, but it force me to redesign my class structure in project.